# Unable to upload files to directory 'file upload path not valid'

Tags: file-uploads

Site has just launched - and no issue with uploaded pdfs previously.

Some pdf links were broken and exisiting files not visible in directories. Trying to re-upload pdf and get message, file upload path is not valid.

Only have CMS access is there anything I can do to resolve and upload the file?

Comment: Please, update your question and tell us the paths of this directory. foamcow's answer can help you on this. Tell us, too, one of the broken links. you can replace your domain by "domain.com" on your data.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will need to update file paths to take into account the new (live) server environment.

If you have Super Administrator access then go to Content->Files->File Upload Preferences and check the paths in there. You will need to specify the paths from the root of your server.

Unfortunately I cannot tell you what *should* be in there.

If you find that your changes don't 'stick' then it may be that the file upload paths are specified in a config file. To edit this you will need access to the server via FTP. There is also the possibility that the site is using multiple config files with something like Focus Labs Config. In which case it gets a little more complicated as there will be separate files for each environment the site is served in (local, dev, staging, production).

You may also find that you will need to update the permissions on the file upload directories but for that you will need access to the server via FTP, SSH or perhaps your hosting company provides a control panel that will allow you to update the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS for this application then your solution for this is to check in your web.config file for requestfiltering section and set the maxAllowedContentLength property. The reason for this is that IIS default max length is only 30MB.